# Android Studio 1.0 Compile Error - Can't have more than one marked region along edge

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio 1.0, and I'm trying to compile a code that I was developing on Eclipse.

But when I compile the code a lot of errors are shown in my image files, like this one:

```
Error:Can't have more than one marked region along edge. - Found at pixel #16 along bottom edge.
```

Why does it occurs in Android Studio and not in Eclipse?
Is there a difference between Eclipse compiler and Android Studio?

Sorry for my English! ;)

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your 9 patch files? Or links to them?

Comment: Nice tutorial on 9 patches: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Answer (score 5):

The left and upper border are for ordering what parts of the drawable can be stretched, and the bottom and right border are for saying where the content is gonna go. The software doesn't allow there to be more than one content area on the bottom and one on the right side. I still cannot show pictures because I don't have any reputation but I think you'll get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a badly-formed nine-patch image, with a gap in the black marker along one of the edges. The error message should tell you which image it is.

Android Studio checks this, as far as I know, Eclipse does not.

Comment: You should **check your 9 patches** by using the **draw9patch tool**. **Eclipse has it** - I don't know if Android Studio offers it, too.