# How do I narrow the right content bound for a 9 patch image?

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

From [Android Studio 1.0 Compile Error - Can't have more than one marked region along edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448559/android-studio-1-0-compile-error-cant-have-more-than-one-marked-region-along) the bottom and right sides define where to put the content.

I have a chat bubble png coming from the right I am converting to a 9patch via draw9patch.  When i draw the right border, I cannot push it inwards to avoid the text going into the triangle portion of the chat bubble.

How do I restrict the text to be contained within the rectangle portion of the chat bubble?

Comment: `'''the bottom and right sides define where to put the content.'''` that's right, so what is your problem actually?

Comment: the text overlaps from the rectangular to triangular portion of the chat bubble.  My right side is a line I drew in the 9patch tool that is on the right side of the image(to the right of the triangle), I cannot move it flush to the rectangular portion of the chat bubble